# How can foreach be faster than loop?

Tags: scala, performance, benchmarking

I did some micro-benchmarks with `foreach` and `while` and to my surprise loop actually lost, though there is less difference with latest version of Scala. Here are the results (Azul JDK 11.0.12 running on M1)

```
Scala 2.13.6

Benchmark                     Mode  Cnt      Score     Error  Units
HashMapBenchmark.vectorMutable  thrpt   10  53220.300 ± 220.481  ops/s
HashMapBenchmark.whileMutable   thrpt   10  49586.007 ±  48.883  ops/s

Scala 2.12.15

Benchmark                     Mode  Cnt      Score     Error  Units
HashMapBenchmark.vectorMutable  thrpt   10  41298.593 ± 245.915  ops/s
HashMapBenchmark.whileMutable   thrpt   10  36607.998 ± 476.617  ops/s
```

Benchmark code

```
  case class Cookie(name: String, value: String)
  
  state.cookies = (1 to 1000).map(i => Cookie(s"name_$i", s"value_$i")).toVector

  @Benchmark
  def vectorMutable(state: BenchmarkState, blackhole: Blackhole): Unit = {
    val map = new mutable.HashMap[String, String]()
    state.cookies.foreach(c => map.put(c.name, c.value))
    blackhole.consume(map)
  }

  @Benchmark
  def whileMutable(state: BenchmarkState, blackhole: Blackhole): Unit = {
    val map = new mutable.HashMap[String, String]()
    var i = 0
    while (i < state.cookies.length) {
      val cookie = state.cookies(i)
      map.put(cookie.name, cookie.value)
      i+=1
    }
    blackhole.consume(map)
  }
```

How is it even possible?

Comment: Not sure to see how it is surprising? `foreach` should be very similar to a `for`, did you benchmark a `for`?

Comment: Well, `foreach` requires creation of lambda and an iterator, with while there's no overhead.

Comment: `foreach` can internally use the most efficient iteration algorithm. In your `while` loop you use indexing. Indexing into a large `Vector` should be much more efficient than indexing into a large `List` but it's not exactly a free operation either.

Comment: Your while implementation has overhead for random access on Vector (which is `eC`), where as sequential access used by foreach does not have this overhead. Even the random access on Array (which is `C`) is not really free.

Comment: Scala Vector is different from Java Vector. It uses a tree instead of an array, which does not provide constant random access https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.html

Comment: @texasbruce Thanks. I really opened a can of worms with this silly benchmark and it turns out results are heavily dependent on Scala and JDK versions. E.g. Scala 2.12 + JDK 17 is very low (30K ops/sec) while 2.13 + JDK 17 is fast.

Comment: Consider that the Scala Collection API has been completely re-implemented in Scala 2.13, which is a likely to be a factor as to why you see this change in performance.

Comment: Given how Vector is implemented, I think you are likely going to observe some difference in performance depending on the size of the Vector itself. If a vector can be fit in a single array I would suspect that indexing-based and foreach-based iteration perform similarly.

Comment: Having a look at the source code, the vector seems to be kept in a single array while it's size is strictly less than 32.

Comment: Changing 1000 to 31 makes the difference less significant, but `foreach` seems to still be more performant.